# Mass update a belongsToMany relationship in a laravel 4 model in a RESTful controller

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an options model that uses a belongsToMany relationship to other options.

I've got my controllers setup in a RESTful scenario. When I PUT an update to the options model, I'm currently updating the model through mass-assignment with the code below:

```
public function update($id)
    {
        $data = Input::json()->all();

        $option = Option::where('id','=',$id)->with('optionRelationValue')->first();
        $option->fill($data['option']);
        $option->save();

        return json_encode(array('option' => $option->toArray()));
    }
```

It's works until I go to update the model with an array of values for "optionRelationValue", as that is the property that drives the relationship.

I'm now getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "ErrorException",
    "message": "Array to string conversion",
    "file": "/[REMOVED]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
    "line": 352
  }
}
```

1. Is it possible to update the model using mass assignment when there is a relationship?
2. If so, how do I update the relationship with new connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my particular issue is two fold.

**#1** I was trying to save an array value into a field and the error was alerting me to this fact. It needed to be converted to a string before saving to the field. A simple implode() solved this for me.

**#2** I was also assuming that laravel would figure out that I had a relationship to modify at the same time and work it's magic for me. WRONG.

My solution to saving the changes to the relationship involved the "attach" and "detach" methods of the model, which are brilliant.